# Sharepoint, How to use MessageBox from C# webpart? or any other javascript sample

Tags: c#, sharepoint, messagebox

How to use MessageBox in C# webpart or what's the altenative?

I want to use some component like MessageBox in sharepoint webpart, can you heklp me to find a sample or tutorial?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in a website (such as Sharepoint) you'd use the [JavaScript alert() function](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp).

```
<script language="javascript">
   alert("I am an alert box!");
</script>
```

Also included in the link above, the confirm() pop-up and the prompt() pop-up, which allow you to get input back from the user, not just show a pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is that all the code is on the C# side here a sample

```
some code
```

DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Is Dot Net Perls awesome?",
        "Important Question",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

if (result1)
{
some code
}

I lunch the alert from c# code.

DialogResult result1 = MessageBox.Show("Is Dot Net Perls awesome?",
        "Important Question",
        MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

Any tutoriel? or example?

Thanks.